Supremum of sums of functions in $L^1$ taking random signs
Consider the Banach space $X=L^1([0,1])$, and let $n\gg1$ and $x_1, ..., x_n$ be any points in the unit sphere of $X$.
Is there any reasonable lower bound for $$\sup_{(\epsilon_i)_{i=1}^n \in \{-1,+1\}^n} \left\Vert \sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i x_i \right\Vert_{L^1} $$
as $n$ goes to $\infty$? Can this stay bounded?
If $X = \mathbb R^k$ for some $k < n$, we can argue using pigeonhole principle and dividing the sphere in sectors to show that the supremum is at least comparable to $\frac n k$.
EDIT: I wasn't sure about how to title the question. If any moderator has a more appropriate name, please change it.

Yeah. It is at least $c\sqrt n$ and you cannot guarantee much more. Just use the random choice and estimate the expectation pointwise for the lower bound using the inequality $\sqrt{|a_1|^2+\dots+|a_n|^2}\ge \frac{|a_1|+\dots+|a_n|}{\sqrt n}$ and take $x_m(t)=e^{2\pi i mt}$ to get the $\sqrt n$ upper bound even for the $L^2$-norm and any choice of signs.

Thanks @fedja !
